# What is the default caching behavior for Apache CachingHttpClientBuilder?

Tags: java, caching, httpclient, cache-control

I assume that Apache HttpClients built using the CachingHttpClientBuilder will honor the `Cache-Control` headers returned on responses, e.g. caching responses that say `Cache-Control: public` and not caching responses that say `Cache-Control: no-store`.  But what does it do if the response just doesn't contain a `Cache-Control` header?  Does it cache by default or not cache by default?

Comment: funny how I was sure there is a good documentation about this, I will just find it and present it in the comment here. To my surprise, this is not nearly the case